# vb.net Unable to keep decimal places when converting string to single

Tags: string, vb.net, type-conversion

I have been working on a vb.net project and have run into a problem.  I have tried various implementations from Stackoverflow and MSDN but nothing is working.  All I am trying to do is convert a string value to a single and keep the precision.

An example of the code would be something like this:

```
Dim Total As Single = 0 
Dim s as String = "427.00"
Total += Single.Parse(s)
```

// Total = 427

// Expected : 427.00  <-- I need this

I have tried using cultureinfo.invariant,
I have tried using string.format,
I have tried using double instead of single,

I don't know what I am missing. 
Any insight would be appreciated, and I can provide more code of what the application is trying to do if necessary.

Comment: 427 == 427.00 if you want `Total` to be a `string` then `Dim Total As String` and use another varible for addition.

Comment: I want 'Total' to be a Single

Comment: from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/single-data-type): `Trailing Zeros. The floating-point data types do not have any internal representation of trailing 0 characters. For example, they do not distinguish between 4.2000 and 4.2. Consequently, trailing 0 characters do not appear when you display or print floating-point values. `

Comment: Conclusion: If you want any format representation of your number, use .ToString("format"). For calculations, trailing zeros are absolutely not relevant.

Comment: Oh wow.. thanks for clearing that up.  I totally got hung up on one number (ex, 417.00) that had zeros and wasn't getting why it was dropping the zeros.  But it makes sense now and everything is working as it should for values after the decimal that are not zero.  Thanks!

Comment: In general, you might as well use the Double type instead of Single. The latter will only bring problems and no useful performance gain. For monetary values, use the Decimal type.

Comment: @AndrewMorton agreed, recently came across this in production where million dollar amounts were getting cutoff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @Alex B.'s comment, this is how you would achieve this. `Total` is a `String` but the program will bomb if either is not a `Single` type giving you some type safety.

```
Dim Total As String = "0"
Dim s as String = "427.00"
Total = (Single.Parse(Total) + Single.Parse(s)).ToString("0.00")
```

Comment: You're welcome :-) if it helped and got you to your end goal, feel free to mark as an answer (you get rep, I get rep, everyone wins ;-) )